# ExecuteNonQuery of insert function fired successfully but database doesn't update

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-2012, sqlconnection, windows

I try to insert data into my database, all operations are done successfully but database does not update after the SQL query was executed. It is windows based application. I put the connection string in `app.config` file.

When I run this application code. and insert the data it show me the msg "Data inserted", but when I check the database there no data updated in database.... give me some solution.

I use Visual Studio 2013 and SQL Server 2012.

Here is my code:

```
namespace Sample
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cons"].ConnectionString.ToString());
                sqlcon.Open();
                string str = "insert into tab(name,pwd) values('" + textBox1.Text.ToString() + "','" + textBox2.Text.ToString() + "')";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, sqlcon);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Data inserted");
                cmd.Clone();
            }
            catch(Exception E)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No data inserted");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

App.config

```
<configuration>
   <connectionStrings>
      <add name="cons" 
           connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename='|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf';Integrated Security=True"/>
   </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Show us your **connection string**, please

Comment: With that connection string, VS will copy the data file (`database1.mdf`) to the **output directory** (`.\bin\debug`) where your app runs, and the insert will happens against that file. You're probably just looking at the wrong file, for the data..... you can avoid this by specifying an **absolute, complete path** for your `database1.mdf` instead of relying on `|DataDirectory|` ...

Comment: Well, there is another file in (.\bin\debug) which name is (Database.mdf). it is updated while i'm running the application. but the (Database1.mdf) is not updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hey i solve this problem myself

i just replace the full path in connection string with (|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf).... like this

```
<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="cons" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename='C:\Users\Dhaval\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Sample\Sample\Database.mdf';Integrated Security=True"/>
</connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

so the connection string access right database of application..  not(.\bin\debug) "Database.mdf" file..

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, to prevent injection attacks and to avoid syntax errors, use parameters. Secondly, to ensure resources are properly disposed of, use the "using" statements. Thirdly, show the error message thrown. The following (untested) code illustrates these techniques. Also, what is the cmd.Clone() used for?

```
     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cons"].ConnectionString.ToString());
        try
        {
            using (sqlcon)
            {
                sqlcon.Open();
                string str = "insert into tab(name,pwd) values(@Value1, @Value2)";
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, sqlcon))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Value1", TextBox1.Text));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Value2", TextBox2.Text));
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("Data inserted");
                    //cmd.Clone(); 
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception E)
        {
            throw new Exception(E.Message);

        }
        finally
        {
            sqlcon.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: ok, this is work nicely, but steel the problem is same.. database not updated... nothing is inserted in table. :(

Comment: i think there is no problem with above code..... may be the problem with sql server manager......  but how it works i don't know....